# Using Framer motions useViewportScroll and scrollY with react-intersection-observer

Tags: reactjs, intersection-observer, framer-motion

I am having some trouble using Framer motions useViewportScroll and scrollY with react-intersection-observer. I have some type that is connected to the scroll position on the y axis, so as you scroll up it moves up into place and then if you were to scroll back down the process is reversed. I have a few of these sections so would like to use intersection-observer so that they only happen when the element is in view. But I just can't figure it out.

It's no problem setting up intersection-observer and giving the element an initial of say y:100 and then an animate of y:0 but what I want to use is something like this `const y1 = useTransform(scrollY, [0, 500], [150, 0]);` Anyone got any tips?

Comment: FYI, framer motion has `useInView` hook And every `motion` element has `onViewportEnter` and `onViewportLeave` props.